# My animation code for CSS is not working bounceInUp

Tags: jquery, html, css

My bounceInUp CSS animation is not working. The intention is to make the heading bounce from down to up but it just stays at the top. It doesn't bounce...Pls check my code.

```
<section class="intro">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInUp" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
        <h1><font famliy="Comic Sans MS">EnvironCare</font></h1>
      </section>
      <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="bounceInUp" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
        <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Where is the code that's actually doing the animation? I would assume you're using some kind of JS or CSS library triggered from the `data-os-*` attributes...?

Comment: Note that the correct attribute on the `<font>` element is `family`, not `famliy`, however the `font` tag itself was deprecated a *long* time ago. I'd strongly suggest you remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this website https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp it gives you some examples of animations in css.